# Link gtkmm 3.0 without pkg-config with CMake on windows

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, clion, gtkmm

I want to build a GTK+ application with C++ for windows and linux (gnome) but I have trouble to find a way to link gtkmm library on windows with CMake in Clion. Since pgk-config with MSYS2 won't work, I try to find a way to link it without pkg-config.

I installed MSYS2 and installed GTK+ with pacman as mentioned on their website. I also installed gcc, pkg-config, gtkmm with pacman. (Everything on Windows 10)

```
project(GTKTest)

set(PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\share\\pkgconfig")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

find_package(PkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(GTKMM REQUIRED gtkmm-3.0)

include_directories(${GTKMM_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${GTKMM_LIBRARY_DIRS})

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} ${GTKMM_LIBRARIES})
```

"CMakeLists.txt:9 (pkg_check_modules)" fails and throws "A required package was not found"

What do you suggest to how to set up CMake in order to build on Windows and Linux (Gnome) properly with included binaries for the application. I did not try it yet on Linux but I think it won't be as painful as with windows.

Comment: For `pkg-config` being able to work, it needs a `.pc` file which describes a package. Do you have the one for `gtkmm` package? If yes, where it is located and what exact its name?

Comment: I am not sure if I have it. I installed `pkg-config` with MSYS2 `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-pkg-config`. It's located in C:\msys64\... . I also installed gtkmm with MSYS. I don't know how MSYS works, so hoped that it will do it for me.

Comment: You say "Since pgk-config with MSYS2 won't work", so it is unlikely MSYS2 provides you `.pc` file for `gtkmm`. Without that file `pkg-config` cannot find that package. For being clear: that file is not provided with `pkg-config` utility, it can be provided only with `gtkmm` package itself.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Where do I get the pc file? Do I have to let pkg-config find thr lib in MSYS somehow? Or is it just better to build gtkmm by myself and link it statically somehow?

Comment: I'm not expert for Windows and MSYS, and I don't know how to obtain that file. But without it `pkg-config` won't find gtkmm, I'm sure about that.

Comment: Ok. Then it might be better to get back to my actual question, if there is a way to link gtkmm dynamically on windows which then is also reliable on linux. pkg-config seems to make trouble on windows espacially in combination with MSYS